# How to make db path after uploading image at nodejs with mongoose

Tags: node.js

I am making image upload router with multer at nodejs.
The image upload works well with multer making a folder.
After that, I want to make db path about the imagae uploaded.
But I don't know how it can be done.

The image is sent by **'form-data'** having the name **'selectedFile'**.
And I thought that DB should be made inside this router and
the title, artist, workDoneDate should be loaded by req.body.

But when I try to that with Postman, It can't send 'form-data' and 
req.body Json data at the same time. 
Could you give me some idea or solution how db is made after image uploading?

```
router.post('/create', upload.single('selectedFile'), async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { file } = req; 

    // Here is the problem. 
    const { title, artist, workDoneDate } = req.body;

    const result = {
      originalName: file.originalname,
      size: file.size,
    };

    console.log(title);
    const imagePath = result.originalName;

    // const work = new Work({
    //   title,
    //   artist,
    //   workDoneDate,
    //   imagePath,
    // });
    //
    // await work.save();

    res.json(result.originalName);
  } catch (e) {
    next(e);
  }
});
```

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/501 Maybe it can give you some hints

Comment: why dont you use `req.file.path`